# How to integrate project Expressjs with jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: jquery, node.js, file-upload, socket.io, express

jQuery-File-Upload works well with Nodejs, but I found it difficult to integrate with Expressjs. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks for your attention.

PD: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: did you managed it? I'm still having troubles with the integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

express has formidable baked in via Connect's multi-part middleware e.g. you can simply POST files to an particular route and then use [req.files](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) to handle anything that has been uploaded.

A very simple option for handling file uploads is via the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), and if you're using Jade as your template engine, you simply need a form that has a file input and the plugin should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 10):

there also exist a middleware for express : https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware

Comment: I'm getting the "Cannot POST /uploads", "Cannot GET /uploads" and so on trying to integrate it in express. Do you know, how integrate the same view as the jquery-file-upload to an express app (server)? (I did not get the concept of the integration described in the manual)

Comment: You get an error if you don't have ImageMagick install. If you're on Mac just `brew install imagemagick` and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable within your app, and make sure you don't have any async items (such as things that call a database) in your app.use() chain before formidable because they can cause you to loose data. Also be sure it's in an app.post(), not app.get() handler.

https://github.com/nfriedly/picsync-server/blob/master/app.js#L98 has a rough but working example of using express with formidable.